# Google Apps Script Regular Expression to remove '|' single quote, pipe, single quote - causing timeout

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, timeout

I am cleaning up a poorly formed "csv like" file and saving the file to drive.

This regular expression is causing my script to timeout after 30 minutes on a large file.  When the file is only 10 records it runs fine.

```
var content = content.replace(/['|']/g, "|"); // Replaces the "'|'"
```

When I remove that one regular expression and run the command below, it runs fine in about 2 minutes for 20k records.

```
var content = content.replace(/\r\n\d{1,5}\|/g, "\r\n~~$&").replace(/\r\n/g, "").replace(/~~/g, "\r\n");
```

I have tried about 50 variations on the above regex and I cannot get it to work.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you change the `var content = content.replace(/['|']/g, "|"); // Replaces the "'|'" ` by `var content = content.replace(/'\|'/g, "|");` also add an example of input and expected output please

Answer (score 2):

This line does not do what you think: it will replace all `'` and `|` in your file by `|`

```
var content = content.replace(/['|']/g, "|"); // Replaces the "'|'"
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/WpSWC1/2/

if you want to replace only the pattern `'|'` by `|` then you should use

```
var content = content.replace(/'\|'/g, "|");
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/ntwF4a/1

as the use of `[` `]` in regex defines a range of character:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

This might not be enough to solve your timeout issue on your `20k records`. You might have to split it in smaller part and process them individually.

Comment: The file processes in less than 3 minutes with 20k records until I try and replace the '|' with a pipe.  It's supposed to be outputting a pipe delimited csv file.  The file I get is single quote - pipe delimited.  The Utilities.parseCsv doesn't like that '|' delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It should work, and it does work on the small file.